# How to round up float value to hundredth value in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have given some examples of what solution I want for my problem statement.

```
#I want this solution
#Example - 

120.21 => 200.0
51.12 => 100.0
1.0 => 100.0
1.5 => 100.0
122100.51 => 200000.0 #Consider this best case
```

Comment: [`Float#ceil`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Float.html#method-i-ceil) takes negative arguments too. `120.21.ceil(-2) #=> 200`

Comment: What did you try? Why didn't it work? What did you try to debug the problem? Where are you stuck? Which parts of the documentation are not clear to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirements are not completely clear to me. But it feels to me like you

- always want to round up to the nearest hundreds
- but if the number is already above 999 then you just want to round up to the next number that looks nice.
- And, although you round the number, you still want to return a float and not an integer.

```
MIN_DIGITS_TO_ROUND = 2

def ceil_plus(float)
  digits = [Math.log10(float), MIN_DIGITS_TO_ROUND].max
  float.ceil(-digits).to_f
end

ceil_plus(120.21)    #=> 200.0
ceil_plus(51.12)     #=> 100.0
ceil_plus(1.0)       #=> 100.0
ceil_plus(1.5)       #=> 100.0
ceil_plus(122100.51) #=> 200000.0
```